# How to have Navigation Bar in UIPopover using Storyboard?

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, uistoryboard

I would like to have a navigation bar in my popover using storyboard.

When I try to accomplish it by referring the button to pop up to navigation controller (that refers to my pop up screen) in my storyboard:

[image]

Then, I try to assign the delegate to my pop up controller:

```
  CheckBoxListingViewController *rdvc = [segue destinationViewController];
  rdvc.delegate = self;
```

But it always returns null in pop up controller when I try to NSLog it.

I think the cause is because of I refer to navigation controller instead of directly refer to pop up controller since when I refer it directly, the delegate is not null anymore.

What can I do to accomplish these screens? Any suggestion? Many thanks!

Comment: can you show us code and screenshots of the storyboard linkings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`destinationController` is referring to your `UINavigationController` Try this:

```
CheckBoxListingViewController *foo = (CheckBoxListingViewController *)((UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController).topViewController;
```

Comment: @Michael Kernahan : your answer just helped me solve my problem (accessing topViewController). You can write your answer to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591559/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-popover-view-controller-inside-a-navigation-controll) and I will validate it as the correct one.

Comment: Thanks - added comment to the guy who was almost there. :-)